# Handling frames with IE11 Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The iframe I want to swtich to has codes:

```
<iframe name="AAA" width="100%" height="100" id="BBB" src="/CCC/blank.html" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="height: 399px;" allowtransparency="true" onload="this.height=100;resize();"></iframe>
```

I am running in a "cell by cell" mode so I believe it is not an issue with the "wait". I have loaded the page already. I then run the code in the cell.

I have tried all these and none worked.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.switch_to.frame(1)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='BBB']"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("BBB"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("AAA"))

driver.switch_to.frame('AAA')
driver.switch_to.frame('BBB')
```

What I did was using Chrome to inspect the elements and come back to IE11. I got the RelXPath and AbsXPath for the element inside the frame. However, I am not able to locate the file with IE11. I believe this is an issue with IE11 working with frames/iframes. The reason I am building my code with IE11 is that I can only access the database with IE11 when I an not using the office network.

All gave me NoSuchElementException
I am using Jupyter Notebook and IE11.

Below is the table content I want to get inside the frame:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody><tr align="center">
                                            <td style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 0px 2px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(203, 203, 196); border-image: none; padding-left: 18px;" colspan="2">
                                                <table width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
                                                <tbody><tr align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <td width="17%" class="fontBold">
                                                        Policy Number
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="20%">
                                                        1710706
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="23%" class="fontBold">
                                                        Request Received Date
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="20%">
                                                        Jul 28, 2002
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="3">
                                                        <a onclick="submitForm('POS1710450285'); return false;" href="javascript:void%200">
                                                            <img width="32" height="32" title="Form/Correspondence" src="/iAES/images/policy/aaa.gif" border="0"><br>
                                                            POS&nbsp;Form / Correspondence
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>


                                                    <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                                        <td class="fontBold">
                                                            Change Type
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="SmallFontStyle" colspan="4">
                                                            Others Request
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
```

I just want to get the text inside the table. The most straightforward way would be switching to the relevant iframe. Should I do a workdaround by getting the text of all td in the page and get any text after "Policy Number" and up to `<td class="SmallFontStyle" colspan="4">`?

Comment: are you sure the iframe is displayed the same why how you see it in the chrome? have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` in the IE 11 console to make sure the iframe exists? What did you got when you tried `document.getElementById('BBB')`? Also checked if the iframe is wrapped in another iframe?

Comment: `items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
print(items)` shows nothing. I believe IE11 is not reading the iframe as Chrome. That's why I can't even get the iframe with index 0. However I do feel that the webpage uses frame with my visual impression on how the page loads. When I do `document.getElementById('BBB')`, I got `NoSuchFrameException: Message: BBB`

Comment: seems to be there are no iframes in the IE11. have you checked the `td` in IE11 if it's really holds the ifame?

Comment: This is what I see in IE11: `<td> <iframe...> <html><head></head><body...>...</body></html></iframe></td>`

Comment: I belive IE11 or the webpage does not load as we think. The first page I click is POS records of all policies of all clients. Then I click a link on to open up a POS record. I see there is a frame loading in the same window visually. However, when I go through the source code there is names of other client that should only be visible on the page before I click the link.